# How to cluster Redis service

Tags: linux, centos, cluster, redis

Imagine 6 servers running Redis on all of them:

```
192.168.10.1
192.168.10.2
192.168.10.3
192.168.10.4
192.168.10.5
192.168.10.6
```

They have divided into 2 site:

Site 1

```
192.168.10.1
192.168.10.2
192.168.10.3
```

Site2

```
192.168.10.4
192.168.10.5
192.168.10.6
```

There is no Sentinel behind any Redis. I just want to make a cluster like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDbce.jpg)

How to define this cluster on each server? What is the respective command for each node?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: What commands have you tried already? What errors?